# Azure DevOps API: Update query with clauses

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to read a query, and add a new clause, and save it elsewhere, using the C# Azure DevOps SDK. I was able to do this by updating the new query's .Wiql directly and modifying the string. However I would rather do this by updating the .Clauses field directly. Unfortunately, using the .Clauses field ends up doing nothing - the Wiql takes precedence. If I set the Wiql to be empty, the Clauses also don't seem to take effect either.

I'm using GetQueryAsync() to get the query, and UpdateQueryAsync() to save it. For example:

```
await workItemTrackingClient.UpdateQueryAsync(outputQuery, c_projectName, outputQueryId);
```

Any input appreciated.